# .net application proxy with WPAD

Tags: c#, .net, proxy

One of our customers uses a Proxy which is configured using WPAD. All of their employees have to have the "Automatically detect settings" checkbox ticked in the Internet Explorer internet options. No further configuration is required.

We implemented a proxy functionality in our app by adding the following code in our app.config:

```
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

We can not test this setup currently, so I have to ask: Will this configuration be sufficient to run our app in our customers environment?

More specific: Do I need to specifically provide the "scriptLocation" Attribute to the "proxy" Element, so that the application can find the WPAD file on the server? Like so:

```
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
        <proxy autoDetect="True" scriptLocation="http://url.to/wpad.dat"/>
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

It is suggested [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/fze2ytx2(v=vs.110).aspx) that the WPAD file is found automatically. However im still not sure about out configuration.

Thanks!